# TypeError: contact() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name' -why I get such error in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Hello I am learning django framework for web development. After makemigrations and migrate command I did runserver command hence I got the following error.

> File "D:\learn django\ashokWeb\portfolio\home\views.py", line 21, in
> contact
> ins=contact(name=name,email=email,phone=phone,desc=desc)
> TypeError: contact() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
> [06/Jun/2021 15:08:25] "POST /contact HTTP/1.1" 500 64573

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from home.models import contact

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')

def projects(request):
    return render(request, 'projects.html')

def contact(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        name=request.POST['name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        phone=request.POST['phone']
        desc=request.POST['desc']
        #print(name,email,phone,desc)
        ins=contact(name=name,email=email,phone=phone,desc=desc)
        ins.save()
        print('the deta has been written to the db')
        
    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

'''models.py file'''

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null='True')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    desc = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Your view and model **both** are named `contact` hence when you write `contact(name=name,email=email,phone=phone,desc=desc)` you are actually calling your view function, rename one of them...

Comment: I rename model class name(contact) to contact_mod and still get the same error as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

class start with capital latter ,make changes like contact to Contact in model.py

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32719939)